# How to compare date

Tags: formula

I need to create a workflow in which I need to compare:
If created date is greater than 1st december 2015, then workflow rule must fire. I am unable to achieve it. Can anybody please help.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the Rule criteria as Formula evaluates to true and use the below formula

```
DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) > DATE(2015,12,1)
```